# Count Variable with multiple values in SAS

Tags: sas, bioinformatics

I have a dataset with patients and their age of onset of certain diseases. I want to look at the frequency of these ages of onset relative to decade. However, some patients have multiple diseases, resulting in multiple ages of onset.

The data looks like this. If a patient does not have the disease, the age is 0.

```
IDNUM    HOHTAge HOGDAge CelDAge
1         25       26       15  
2         65       32       0
3         21       12       59
```

I was thinking I need to compile these into a single variable and create a frequency table with them, but this possible/ is there a better solution?

In the end, I want to do something like

```
IF AgeOnset LE 29 THEN AGEGROUP = 0;
ELSE IF 30 LE AgeOnset LE 39 THEN AGEGROUP = 1;
ELSE IF 40 LE AgeOnset LE 49 THEN AGEGROUP = 2;
ELSE IF 50 LE AgeOnset LE 59 THEN AGEGROUP = 3;
ELSE IF AGEOnset GE 60 THEN AGEGROUP = 4;

PROC FREQ; TABLES AGEGROUP;
```

Comment: What's wrong with your current solution? Also how does decade fit in here? You mentioned it but it's not on your example dataset.

Comment: @superfluous I want to count the number of diseases that onset in each decade, and compare which decades are more common, compare the progression of diseases, etc.

Comment: You need to explain the first table more. I would recommend separating out onset by disease and/or looking at first onset if the diseases are related.

Comment: What does your data look like for patients with multiple diseases? Do you have multiple observations of one such patient? I don't think it's clear from your original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get your agegroup variable and then I like proc sql

```
proc sql;
    create table agegroups as
    select 
     count(case when HOHTAge>0 then 1 end) as HOHT_freq,
     count(case when HOGDAge>0 then 1 end) as HOGD_freq
     from dataset 
     group by AGEGROUP;
quit;
```